# Search service on DateTime SPPropertyBag field

Tags: date-time, sharepoint-search, managed-property, crawled-property

In short, the question is that: Is there a way (for the sake of knowledge, any way) to tell search crawler about what particular string format of DateTime value is to expect when crawling mapped properties?

Context: We have a SharePoint 2016 farm with a number of site collections. In these site collections, on root level web, there are some propertybag values, representing dates, which are populated and used by an external custom application. Due to region standards (and old history), these fields are saved as string in 'dd.MM.yyyy' format. SP Web region settings, also server regional settings, have also been set to region, where this date format is customary.

In Search Service, these properties are mapped to managed properties, with a type of Date and Time, marked as searchable, queryable, etc.
But after a crawl, a test search query based on these MPs shows, that Date and Time properties were indexed and converted based on 'MM.dd.yyyy' instead of 'dd.MM.yyyy'. On the other hand, other date formats like 'dd.MMM.yyyy' or 'yyyy-MM-dd' are parsed correctly.

I can't quite understand is there a setting or an algorithm on how search crawler chooses which date format to apply during crawl.